# How perform SQLite query with a data reader without locking database?

Tags: c#, locking, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using System.Data.Sqlite to access SQLite database in C#. I have a query which must read through rows in a table. While iterating through the rows and while the reader is open, certain SQL updates must be performed. I am running into a "database is locked" exception.

The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) states:

> When a process wants to read from a database file, it followed the following sequence of steps:
>
> 1. Open the database file and obtain a SHARED lock.

The documentation further states about "SHARED" locking:

> The database may be read but not written. Any number of processes can hold SHARED locks at the same time, hence there can be many simultaneous readers. But no other thread or process is allowed to write to the database file while one or more SHARED locks are active.

The [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) states:

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in time, however.

The book [The Definitive Guide to SQLite](http://books.google.com/books?id=qAr_U2QRf5IC&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=sqlite+read+uncommitted&source=bl&ots=YJhi2Dc639&sig=9kFCz9z6xSK56zCX-MoLZq1dwWc&hl=en&ei=35SFTbK_ApKw0QGz8Om_CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=sqlite%20read%20uncommitted&f=false) states:

> ...a connection can choose to have a *read-uncommitted* isolation level by using the **read_uncommited** pragma. If it is set to **true**, then the connection will not put read locks on the tables it reads. Therefore, another writer can actually change a table as the connection in read-uncommitted mode can neither block nor be blocked by any other connections.

I attempted to set the pragma to read uncommitted within the SQL query command statement as follows:

```
PRAGMA read_uncommitted = 1;
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable
```

A SQL update on the same thread using a different connection still failed with a "database is locked" exception. I then attempted to set the isolation level to read uncommitted on the connection instance. Still no change with the same exception.

How can I accomplish having an open data reader to loop through rows in the database without locking the database, so that I can execute updates?

**Update:**

Both answers below work. I have however since moved away from using the default rollback journal to now using the Write-Ahead Logging, which provides improved concurrency of database reads and writes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [WAL](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) mode.

Comment: I am using ADO.Net. According to http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ the version of System.Data.SQLite.dll is 1.0.66.0 Apr 18, 2010 and the version of SQLite is 3.6.23.1. It appears that I need version 3.7+ to utilize WAL. Any suggestions? Is there an updated ADO.Net provider?

Comment: Yes, see http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki  version 1.0.68.0 of February 2011 is a code merge with SQLite 3.7.5

Comment: It looks promising; unfortunately I didn't see anything ready or available for download yet... Is the release you mention 1.0.68.0 officially available, or is this an alpha/beta?

Comment: The source code is available for download; the build system is still a work in process due to the complexity of the various build tools and targets, as I understand it.

Comment: I have an up to date source version here: https://github.com/PaulS/SQLiteDotNetProvider. It is for vs2008, uses the old build system that still works. There seems to be no eta for completion of their new project build. I have incorporated the code changes from the official project, there are very few.

Comment: Perhaps make a copy of db file and read from it while modifying the original? Its sql LITE after all:)

Comment: With System.Data.SQLite.Core, you can do this by adding "journal mode=Wal" to the connection string

Comment: @DougCurrie any tips for me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275855/how-do-i-lock-an-entire-sqlite-connection-locked-read-locked-write)?

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to get this to work using the open source data provider from [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). However, I was able to get this to work using the free Standard Edition of [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/download.html) as follows:

Create the below DLL import, so that we can enable the shared cache for SQLite.

```
[DllImport("sqlite3.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int enable);
```

Execute the above function to enable the shared cache. Note, this only needs to be executed once for the entire process - see [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_shared_cache.html).

```
sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(1);
```

Then prefix the SQL query statement used by the data reader with the pragma statement as follows:

```
PRAGMA read_uncommitted = 1;
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable
```

One can now freely update and insert rows while the data reader is active. Additional SQLite documentation on the shared cache can be found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html).

**Update:**

A newer version of the Devart SQLite data provider now supports this in an improved manner. 
To enable the shared cache one can make the following call:

```
Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.EnableSharedCache();
```

One can configure the uncommitted reads into the connection string for example as follows:

```
Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ReadUncommitted = true;
builder.DateTimeFormat = Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDateFormats.Ticks;
builder.DataSource = DatabaseFilePath;
builder.DefaultCommandTimeout = 300;
builder.MinPoolSize = 0;
builder.MaxPoolSize = 100;
builder.Pooling = true;
builder.FailIfMissing = false;
builder.LegacyFileFormat = false;
builder.JournalMode = JournalMode.Default;
string connectionString = builder.ToString();
```